# Laravel: Error while using envoy in Controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-envoy

I try to start "envoy run..." in a controller (or later a Job).

Here is my code so far:

https://laravel.io/bin/Xy207

All I get is this error:

```
ProcessFailedException in ForgeController.php line 28: The command "~/.composer/vendor/bin/envoy run updateenv --provider_id=49" failed.

Exit Code: 1(General error)

Working directory: /Users/hoteldatenservice/code/fewoweb

Output:

Valet requires Brew to be installed on your Mac.

Error Output:

Valet and Brew are installed on my Mac.
```

Any idea why I can do?

Thanks

kay899

Answer (score 0):

kay899, are you running Valet? I had the same issue. The only sort of workaround I have is to comment out:

// if (exec('which brew') == '' && ! $inTestingEnvironment) {
//     echo 'Valet requires Homebrew to be installed on your Mac.';

//     exit(1);
// }

from https://github.com/laravel/valet/blob/master/cli/includes/compatibility.php

$inTestingEnvironment seems to be not working.